# fgets() strtok()

Tags: c, malloc, fgets, strtok

Hey my assignment is to read in data from a file that is separated by spaces and sort the data. I keep getting a seg fault and I can't figure out whats wrong with my code. Thanks for the help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 100
#define MAX_NAME 30
int countLinesInFile(FILE* fptr);
int findPlayerByName(char **names, char* target, int size);
int findMVP(int* goals, int* assists, int size);
void printPlayers(int* goals, int* assists, char** names, int size);
void allocateMemory(int **goals, int** assists, char*** names, int size);
void sortPlayersByGoals(int* goals, int* assists, char** names, int size);
void writeToFile(FILE *fptr, int* goals, int* assists, char** names, int size);
void readLinesFromFile(FILE* fptr, int* goals, int* assists, char** names, int        numLines);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    int size;
    int* goals;
    int* assists;
    char** names;
    if(argc != 2)
    {
            printf("Invalid number of arguments\n");
            return 1;
    }
    fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
            printf("Failed to open input file.\n");
            return 2;
    }
    size = countLinesInFile(fptr);
    allocateMemory(&goals, &assists, &names, size);
    int numLines;
    numLines = size;
    readLinesFromFile(fptr, goals, assists, names, numLines);
    printPlayers(goals, assists, names, size);

    return 3;
}
void printPlayers(int* goals, int* assists, char** names, int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    printf("%c     %d     %d", *(names + i), *(goals + i), *(assists + i));
    }

}
void readLinesFromFile(FILE* fptr, int* goals, int* assists, char** names, int numLines)
{
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    int i;
    char* value;

    for(i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
    {
            fgets(line, MAX_LINE, fptr);
            value = strtok(line, " ");
            *(*names + i) = atoi(value);
            value = strtok(line, " ");
            *(goals + i) = atoi(value);
            value = strtok(line, " ");
            *(assists + i) = atoi(value);
    }


}
void allocateMemory(int **goals, int** assists, char*** names, int size)
{

    *goals = malloc(sizeof(int)* size);
    *assists = malloc(sizeof(int)* size);
    *names = malloc(sizeof(char*)* MAX_NAME);

}
int countLinesInFile(FILE* fptr)
{
    int i;
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    i = 0;
    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, fptr) != NULL)
    {
    i++;
    }
    rewind(fptr);
    return i;
}
```

-- INSERT --

input file looks like:
Redden 2 0
Berglund 5 2
Jackman 2 0
Stewart 4 0
Oshie 3 5
McDonald 2 4
Pietrangelo 2 7
Perron 2 6
Tarasenko 5 5

Comment: put printf's in your code to give us a basic idea of where it's bombing at. Or post the input as well so we can test it ourselves :)

Comment: WOW! A [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) :)

Comment: input file is: 
Redden 2 0
Berglund 5 2
Jackman 2 0
Stewart 4 0
Oshie 3 5
McDonald 2 4
Pietrangelo 2 7
Perron 2 6
Tarasenko 5 5

Answer (score 0):

In allocateMemory(), each `*names` is a `char **`. You need to allocate twice

```
*names = malloc(...);
for (<each pointer in names>) {
    <pointer> = malloc(...);
}
```

Don't forget to free twice too

```
for (<each pointer in names>) {
    free(<pointer>);
}
free(*names);
```

Answer (score 0):

About your segmentation fault, you are dereferencing the pointer `**names`, but `*names` is an unitialized pointer. This leads to an undefined behavior, hence the execution error in your case (and it could be worst!). To solve it, you have to allocate a bi-dimensionnal array, for instance:

```
*a = malloc(numLines * sizeof **a);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) (*a)[i] = malloc(NAME);
```

Moreover your `strtok` utilisation seems to be wrong. This function keeps a static pointer to  your data (therefore it is often not thread-safe): you shall use the value `NULL`  in the next calls. Otherwise, it will return the same address every time. Check the documentation by typing `man strtok`in your favorite web search engine.

```
char line[MAX_LINE];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < numLines; i++)
{
    fgets(line, sizeof line, fptr);
    value = strtok(line, " ");
    (*names)[i] = atoi(value); /* This assignment looks strange. */
    value = strtok(NULL, " ");
    goals[i] = atoi(value);
    value = strtok(NULL, " ");
    assits[i] = atoi(value);
}
```

Don't forget the array subscripting operator! If it is a real-world program, `sscanf` looks more suitable.

Comment: i have to use fgets and strtok, its for a class assignment

Comment: @user2093120: In that case don't forget to check the documentation. Good luck! ;-)

Comment: as for that line that looks strange, how would you change it? I got the program to read in goals and assists correctly, but it keeps giving me garbage for names

Comment: @user2093120: If you want just strings, why did you use `atoi`? BTW, `strdup` or `malloc`+`strcpy` will work as well.